# Is subset relation axiomatizable?

Tags: model-theory

We know that the ZFC axioms define the elementary class associated with them. And we can extend the signature to a binary relation symbol P and add a defining axiom that says P is the subset relation. So, the subset relation is at least a psuedo-elementary class. My question is, is it also an elementary class?

Comment: Are you asking whether the class of all structures $( M , \subseteq^M )$ where $a \subseteq^M b$ holds iff $a \subseteq b$ is first-order axiomatizable (over the signature $\sigma = \{ \subseteq \}$)?

Comment: No, because there may not be a least element for the relation. I am asking whether the class of ZFC universes with subset is axiomatizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is not an elementary class. I sketch a proof, below, but have not checked in detail an important piece. I might come back and verify the details if I have time.

In the language $L$ containing only $\subseteq$, let $T$ be the theory asserting that $\subseteq$:

- is a lattice,
- has a lower bound but no upper bound,
- has relative complements,
- is atomic (in that everything has an atom below it),
- has infinitely many atoms.

Clearly, the $L$-reduct of ZFC contains $T$. I will show that

1. $T$ is complete, and
2. $T$ has a model not isomorphic to the reduct of any model of ZFC.

***Completeness***

Note that, in $T$, finite (including 0-ary) unions and finite (excluding 0-ary) intersections, as well relative complement are defined, so we might as well include them in $L$ and expand $T$ accordingly. We can similarly expand $L$ and $T$ with predicates $|A| = n$ for every natural number $n$, defined as saying $A$ extends exactly $n$ atoms. A standard back-and-forth argument **should** verify that this theory is complete and eliminates quantifiers (in the expanded $L$). **I didn't check in detail that the back-and-forth works as I expect it does.**

***Model of $T$ that isn't a reduct***

Fix an infinite set $X$, and let $M$ be the $L$-structure consisting of the *finite* subsets of $X$, with $\subseteq$ interpreted as the usual subset relation. Then $M \models T$. $M$ cannot be the reduct of a model of ZFC, however, since any model of ZFC contains an infinite set (and therefore a set extending infinitely many atoms).

Comment: I don't quite understand your proposed back-and-forth argument, since if such an argument were successful, then unless you meant something very different, it would show that the theory is not only complete but also $\aleph_0$-categorical.  (What I mean is that a back-and-forth construction would be aimed at proving that any two countable models are isomorphic.)  But the theory $T$ is not $\aleph_0$-categorical, because some models have points at infinite height and some do not.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @JDH I meant the tests for completeness and quantifier elimination involving finite partial isomorphisms between sufficiently saturated models. See, for example, proofs of QE for algebraically closed fields (which are not countably categorical).

Comment: Ah, that is more complicated, but also more believable. I've got to think about it.